# gfortran and ifort different behavior on function return derived types

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, derived-types

I'm working on a project that requires to store the memory address of an attribute of an derived type in Fortran. What a found is in gfortran, there is an implicit copy of the return of a function if the return is a derived type. So the address I stored is meaningless. There is a piece of code:

```
module atest
!  use iso_c_binding
  type test
    real(8):: a
    real(8):: p
  end type test
  interface
    subroutine pointerprint(a)
      real(8), intent(in) :: a
    end subroutine pointerprint
  end interface
  interface assignment(=)
    module procedure overloadedAsgn
  end interface
contains
  function returnvalue(t)
    type(test), intent(in)::t
    type(test):: returnvalue
    returnvalue%a=t%a+1
    call pointerprint(returnvalue%a)
  end function returnvalue
  SUBROUTINE overloadedAsgn(ret,rhs)
    type(test), intent(inout) :: ret
    type(test), intent(in) :: rhs
    print *, "assign_d"
    ret%a=rhs%a
    ret%p=rhs%p+1.0d0
    call pointerprint(rhs%a)
  end SUBROUTINE overloadedAsgn  

end module

program xxx
  use atest
  type(test):: t
  type(test):: b
  t%a=1.0d0/11.0d0
  t%p=0.0d0
  b=returnvalue(t)
end program 


#include<stdio.h>
void pointerprint_(double *x){
  printf("Addr<%lx>\n",(unsigned long)x);
}
```

The output using gfortran is:

```
Addr<7fff51df24e0>
 assign_d
Addr<7fff51df2520>
```

The outpus using ifort is:

```
Addr<7fffc92e6fc0>
 assign_d
Addr<7fffc92e6fc0>
```

Is there a way to avoid such a copy in gfortran so the result is consistent? I just begin to learn fortran. There might be a descriptor for the function or an option for the compiler.

Comment: How are you calling that C code if you have `use iso_c_binding` commented out? My concern is that something in the interface to the C code is the source of the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting on processor dependent behaviour. The processor may pass by copy-in (and/or out) if it is profitable. You may use pointer dummy arguments to pass a pointer.

You don't have any `TARGET` in your code and still want to rely on pointers to your variables.

Comment: This is interesting! Could you elaborate on this? (Or give a link/book where I could read about this?)

Comment: For gfortran specific conventions see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Argument-passing-conventions.html

Comment: Otherwise I recommend the Fortran 2008 standard and the informative appendixes. For this case section C.9.4 is relevant (regarding usability of pointers to dummy arguments and the `target` attribute).

Comment: Ah I get it - it's the missing `TARGET`, so the compiler is at liberty to do optimizations and not treat it as a pointer. So my answer is definitely wrong. Thanks!